# How to sort grouped data in extjs grid?

Tags: extjs

I am using EXTJS 6.5.3 classic kit. I do want to have sorting functionality with grouping. My grouping field and sorting fields are different. E.g. I am having two fields field 1 and field 2 then I want to have grouping on field 1 and sorting on field 2. But I do want result as 1st it should group with field 1 and then it should sort with field 2. But I do want to sort after grouping.

Thank you in advance. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Extjs 6.7 modern, I doing the similar thing. Although my solution still have problem and may not fit for you, I can share to you.

Modern have Ext.util.Grouper from store.grouper. then the Grouper class can assign

```
sorterFn: function(person1, person2) {
if(person1.field1 == person2.field1 ){
  return 0; // same field 1
}else{
   // different field 1
   // this is just a sample, 
   // could be more complex compare condition basic on your business logic 
   if (person1.field2 > person1.field2 ) {
     return 1 ;
   }else if (person1.field2 === person2.field2){
      if (person1.field1 > person2.field1 ){
         return 1;
      }else{
         return -1;
      }
   }else{
    return -1;
   }
```

}`